# CPU not working on a specific motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I'm making a computer for someone and I met a weird problem. The CPU that I have doesn't work on this motherboard. The CPU is an Intel Pentium D 925 and the motherboard is an ECS G41T-M6, which in theory should work together. The only thing reused is the power source(400W). When I start the computer, the fans start, and that's it. The BIOS doesn't boot.

I tried my own power source (600W Corsair) and nothing. Removed the RAM, no warning. In desperation I tried the last thing, swaped my own CPU with this one (Core2Duo E7200). Lo and behold, it worked. Both. The Core2Duo worked on the ECS with the old power source and the RAM that I used in the first place, and the Pentium D worked on my Gigabyte G31M-ES2L.

What I discovered was that the Pentium D didn't receive power on the ECS, because I tried running it without the cooler and it remained at room temperature. On a side note, I also removed the HDDs just in case.

So, in conclusion, any ideas? I can't return it, and I can still use it to upgrade another PC, but I would really prefer not to buy another CPU if possible.

Comment: I'm still trying to dig up the tech specs for that motherboard, but so far have not found the Pentium-D listed as compatible with it, only Core2Duo/Core2Quad

Comment: Pentium D's have EOL and not been supported for at least 2 and half years. You should not even be able to get them without having to pay higher price then say a Core2Duo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documention for the G41T-M6](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1003&CategoryID=1&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=16&LanID=0#fragment-SPEC), the Pentium D is not among the list of supported processors:

- Core™2 Quad
- Core™2 Duo
- Pentium® Dual Core
- Celeron® Dual Core
- Celeron® 400 series processors

The processor as you discovered works, but just isn't compatible.

Comment: Just to ensure it's noted: A "Pentium Dual Core" is NOT a "Pentium D". :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and clarification, both of you. I could almost smash my head into a wall for this. I hope it works on the other computer, it could use an upgrade and I could use some good news. Thanks again.

Comment: @Shaman If nothing else, the good news is you joined [SU]! Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to refer to your motherboard's documentation to see if perhaps there is a jumper setting that needs to be changed in order to handle this processor.  If there's no other settings, then you might just have a bad processor.  The other troubleshooting option available to you is to put the "bad" processor in your computer and see if it boots.  Removing the hard drives would probably still be recommended when trying this.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported CPU's supported by that board are the following:

Core 2 Quad/Duo / Pentium Dual-Core / Celeron

The Pentium D which has been EOL for awhile now is not supported by the motherboard in question.

Your own motherboard supports the following CPUs:

http://www.gigabyte.us/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=2889

There are about 7 pages of supports CPU's the Pentium D is among them.